# how to get source id from stripe using angular 9

Tags: angular, stripe-payments, stripes

i have used ngx stripe  but this source id is wrong

@ViewChild(StripeCardComponent) card: StripeCardComponent;

cardOptions: StripeCardElementOptions = {
hidePostalCode:true,
style: {
base: {
iconColor: '#666EE8',
color: '#31325F',
fontWeight: '300',
fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
fontSize: '18px',
'::placeholder': {
color: '#CFD7E0'
}
}
}
};

CREATE TOKEN

elementsOptions: StripeElementsOptions = {
locale: 'es'
};

```
createToken(): void {
const name = this.stripeTest.get('name').value;
this.stripeService
  .createSource(this.card.element, {  })
  .subscribe((result) => {
    console.log(result)
    this.sourceId=result.source.id;

   
    
  });
```

}**strong text**

Comment: Hi Anil, it looks like part of your question is missing. Can you please review and edit? It is not clear what the unexpected behaviour is, so please provide more clarity about your issue.

Comment: i want get source id from stripe Payment gateway i have used angular 9 and use  ngx-stripe but generate source id is worng

Comment: What do you mean it is wrong? What do you expect it to be? What is it instead?

Comment: i mean how to get source id from stripe in angular 9

Comment: What's the result of `createSource`? Does it work and have an `id`? What makes you say the "source id is wrong" if you can't retrieve a value?